# Should I define a JPA ManyToOne lazily, or just map the raw id in my entity if I don't really need the referenced data?

Tags: java, hibernate, rest, jpa, quarkus-panache

I have an application that you login with OIDC.
So there is a rest call from the frontend to the Java / JPA backend with a token (identity).
I have a lookup table that assigns each external token ID an internal company ID:

```
@Entity(name = "company_mapping")
public class CompanyMapping {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(generator = "system-uuid")
   @GenericGenerator(name = "system-uuid", strategy = "uuid")
   public UUID id;

   public String externalId;

   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   @JoinColumn(name = "company_id")
   public Company company;
```

For each set of data entries of the company, this company ID is a foreign key.
But I don't really need the company data - or only in rare special cases.
Therefore I am thinking if I should actually retrieve the company each time / how to design the JPA Entities so that the company table just references the company ID and not the entire company - or maybe this doesn't even matter if I make a lazy mapping?

```
  @Entity(name="employee")
   public class Employee 
    @Id @GeneratedValue(generator="system-uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name="system-uuid", strategy = "uuid")
    private UUID id;
    private String email;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    [...]


    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Company company; // TODO maybe just use the company uuid here?
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really do not need to access the company data but just its ID , you can simply map its ID column. YAGNI and KISS. You even do not need to create the `Company` class in this case.

On the other hand , even if you map the company as `@ManyToOne` with `LAZY` fetch type , provided that you will not access the company data besides its ID, from the generated SQL point of view , they are the same as just mapping the ID which no unnecessary SQL will be generated to get the company data.